# shortest way to get activerecord attributes from irb to excel sheet

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, excel

I'm pulling small statistics or bunch of product-data from my erp system from irb-console to excel.
For example some product data:

```
Product.where(active:true, sale:false).map{|p| [p.sku, p.name, p.stock_amount].join("\t")}.each{|s| puts s}
```

the output can be copied and pasted directly to excel. This is the shortest I found for my self. Is there a way with less typing get this done?

Answer (score 1):

What database are you using?  Most databases like Postgresql have a COPY command that allows you to export an active record query filled with data to a csv file which can be opened and resaved as an excel file.  This is probably the fastest and most convenient way as you start to work with larger data-sets.

Comment: sometimes I add select-blocks or other extra-calculation so I have to get it out of the console.

Comment: Are you opposed to saving the results of these calculations in a table then exporting the table to csv?